# Can I change Thymeleaf "include" precedence?

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I use a "head" fragment with Thymeleaf where I store my css links.

I also have a unique css file which I would like to apply only to a given page. My first attempt to achieve this was the method below.

```
<head th:include="fragments/head :: head">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  th:href="@{/css/create-post.css}" />
</head>
```

However it seems the css files from the fragment are inserted **under** the current content of the head tag. This is a problem, because in create-post.css wish to override some styling.

Is there a way to change the precedence how Thymeleaf inserts into the head tag?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but let me give it some tries...

**Suggestion 1)** I have a small project in which some javascript-s are included on every page and some pages include page specific scripts. Here is the definition of the head fragment:

```
<head th:fragment="common_header(title, scripts)">

    <title th:replace="${title}">A title</title>

    <!-- Common scripts -->
    <script 
        src="/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"
        th:src="@{/js/jquery/jquery.min.js}">
    </script>

    ...

    <th:block th:replace="${scripts}">
    </th:block>

</head>
```

Here is a specific page which needs not only jQuery but also an additional script for reCAPTCHA support:

```
<head th:replace="/fragments/commonheader :: common_header(~{::title},~{::script})">

    <title>Register a new user</title>

    <script th:src="@{https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js}"></script>

</head>
```

**Suggestion 2)** Besides `th:include` there is `th:replace`. Whereas `th:include` will include the contents of the fragment into its host tag, `th:replace` will actually substitute the host tag by the fragment’s. Details [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#difference-between-thinclude-and-threplace).

I hope these ideas may help.